# Indefinite Subtrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

While doing tree proofs, sometimes we need to consider a root with some subtrees, but we don't know the exact properties of the subtrees, so we just represent them using triangles. Is it possible to do this using latex, preferably using the tikz package? Or will I have to manually have to draw the triangles? This seems like something that might be quite common, so I guess it should be possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? `tikz-qtree` library might help. There are many examples in the manual and on this site.

Comment: The answer given below is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tikz-qtree` package provides a `[roof]` style for these kinds of nodes for use in linguistic trees. I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.A [.B ]  [.C [.D \edge[roof]; {This is some stuff without internal structure} ] [.E ] ]]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I have to wait to accept, otherwise I'd have accepted already :)